# "They will not give up on the bananas, until they'll be eaten by them or they will be spoiled."

Tags: syntax

I'm always confused whether I have to double the pronoun and auxiliary verb or not, in cases like in the following one:

> "They will not give up on the bananas until they'll be eaten by them
> or **they will be** spoiled."

Should I double it or not?

Comment: I think a more natural wording here is 'until they eat them or they spoil'. My first thought when reading this sentence was of man-eating bananas.

Comment: Yes, it is about men eating bananas)

Comment: @JudiciousAllure, I think you missed Angelo's hyphen. In your sample sentence, the second _they_ (following _until_) is  nost naturally understood to refer to the same as the first _they_, not to the bananas, so it reads that the people are being eaten by bananas.